# Can I use django ModelForms with ndb models?

Tags: django, google-app-engine, django-forms, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb

Using the following sample code:

forms.py

```
from django.forms import ModelForm
from models import System

class SystemForm(ModelForm):
  class Meta:
    model = System
```

models.py

```
from google.appengine.ext import ndb

# Create your models here.
# https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/properties
class System(ndb.Model):
  name = ndb.StringProperty('n')
  heart_beat = ndb.DateTimeProperty('h')
  report = ndb.BooleanProperty('r', default=True)
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from forms import SystemForm

def settings(request):

  return render(request, 'settings.htm', {'form': SystemForm()})
```

I've also added
[`google.appengine.ext.ndb.django_middleware.NdbDjangoMiddleware`](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/#integration) as the first class in my `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES`.

Starting the app returns the error:
`type object 'System' has no attribute '_meta'`

**What is the correct method to implement Django ModelForms with ndb models?**

Comment: Every time I see a question about this, I think "I really must finish my library that makes ndb models work with Django forms and the admin". I promise, I will get around to it eventually.

Comment: @DanielRoseman That would be wonderful :) However I thought the ```NbdDjangoMiddleWare``` mentioned above was supposed to handle that?  The disconnect seems to be that nbd models don't match closely enough with django models.  I've considered trying to generate a class that takes both models as parents - but again I was hoping someone had done that heavy lifting.

Comment: No, that middleware just makes NDB work generally in the Django environment, it doesn't do anything to make it compatible with forms. My half-finished thing is exactly that "heavy lifting" you refer to. Maybe if I spent less time on here I'd be more likely to finish it...